# LINQ search query doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm trying to write a search query in LINQ. Below is the where condition.

```
where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameWithInitials) 
 && tb.NameWithInitials.Contains(nameWithInitials)) 
 && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(studentRegNo) 
    && tbSR.StudentRegistrationNo.Contains(studentRegNo))
 && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(NIC) && tb.NIC.Contains(NIC)) 
 && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName) && tbi.Name.Contains(fullName))
```

It doesn't return any values if I pass a single parameter. For example if I pass 'Chamara' as fullname it doesn't return any result but if I pass all the parameters at the once then it returns the matching records.

I need to get this to work even when I pass several parameters dynamically

Comment: And what should be the result if you don't pass anything? (I mean, all strings are null or empty)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using AND (`&&`) everywhere, so if at least one of these conditions is false, your `where` condition will be false. Try using OR conditions instead:

```
where (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameWithInitials) || tb.NameWithInitials.Contains(nameWithInitials)) 
 && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(studentRegNo) || tbSR.StudentRegistrationNo.Contains(studentRegNo))
 && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NIC) || tb.NIC.Contains(NIC)) 
 && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName) || tbi.Name.Contains(fullName))
```

In this case in any of these conditions if you have empty parameter, only the first part of condition will be evaluated, otherwise the second condition will be evaluated.

One potential issue is that Entity Framework might not be able to translate this to actual SQL. In this case, you can use such approach:

```
var query = // your original query without where condition
// Check if the condition is valid and only then add where condition
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameWithInitials))
{
    query = query.Where(tb => tb.NameWithInitials.Contains(nameWithInitials));
}
// repeat this for all other conditions
```

Comment: I was thinking the same but my mind was cluttered with all those conditions! :)

Comment: EF can translate that. But the 2nd approach is better for readability

Comment: Uhm something is not quite right in the OP request here. What should be the result if all strings are null or empty?

Comment: @Steve In this case the result is full data set, without any filters. If parameter is passed, then additional filter condition is added

Comment: Hello @dotnetom my original query return thousands of data that's why I was trying to get the results in the 1'st approach without getting them to memory

Comment: @chamara In that case you need to ensure that at least one parameter is provided. But the code above ensures that the query works correctly with any number of filter parameters provided

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is semi-confusing but i think you want to search for every string if exists, which translates to

```
where ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(nameWithInitials) 
 || tb.NameWithInitials.Contains(nameWithInitials)) 
 && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(studentRegNo) 
    || tbSR.StudentRegistrationNo.Contains(studentRegNo))
 && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(NIC) || tb.NIC.Contains(NIC)) 
 && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName) || tbi.Name.Contains(fullName))
```